# findbugs maven plugin site vs check

Tags: maven, pom.xml, findbugs

I'm just trying to wrap my head around a couple of things.

If I have this in my `masterpom`:

```
<reporting>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.2</version>
   <configuration>
      <failOnError>false</failOnError>
      <threshold>High</threshold>
      <effort>Default</effort>
      <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
      <skip>${skipFindBugs}</skip>
      <xmlOutputDirectory>target/reports/findbugs</xmlOutputDirectory>
      <excludeFilterFile>
          src/main/resources/findbugs-exclude-filters.xml
      </excludeFilterFile>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</reporting>
```

My `findbugs-exclude-filters.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindBugsFilter>
     <Match>
        <Bug category="I18N" />
     </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

**QUESTIONS**

Why does `clean verify site` report 2 warnings, but `clean verify findbugs:check` return 14 bugs? I don't understand what the difference is.

Why does my `site` report warn about `I18N`:`DM_DEFAULT_ENCODING`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `findbugs-maven-plugin` plugin needs to be configured in **BOTH** the `<reporting><plugins/></reporting>` and `<build><plugins/></build>` section.  Have experimented with this all sorts of ways and the only way I have been able to get it to work is to duplicate `findbugs-maven-plugin` configuration.

So try adding something like the following in your pom.xml:

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.2</version>
   <configuration>
      <failOnError>false</failOnError>
      <threshold>High</threshold>
      <effort>Default</effort>
      <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
      <skip>${skipFindBugs}</skip>
      <xmlOutputDirectory>target/reports/findbugs</xmlOutputDirectory>
      <excludeFilterFile>
          src/main/resources/findbugs-exclude-filters.xml
      </excludeFilterFile>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

Note that it's a cut and paste of what you posted inside of the `<reporting/>` block.  I have not tested the above.  I'm just trying to give you a general idea here.

The [Reporting section of the POM Reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Reporting) states that:

> And the subtler difference is that a plugin configuration under the reporting element works as build plugin configuration, although the opposite is not true (a build plugin configuration does not affect a reporting plugin).

I have been able to make this work with Maven 3.0.5.  I have not tried it on 3.1.0 yet.

Comment: can you please clarify what "version" of maven you have been able to get this to work with? thanks.

Comment: Hey @adam.  Dublicating the `<plugins/>` in both `<reporting/>` and `<build/>` blocks I got working in mvn 3.0.5.  I was not able to get "And the subtler difference is that a plugin configuration under the reporting element works as build plugin configuration" at all.

Comment: The real issue is that Findbugs needs bytecode to work with :: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8939723/64505 :: run `mvn compile site` and it will work with only an entry in the `<reporting/>` section.